# Accessing a column name in the parent

Tags: sql, join

I've got this script :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as nbapp, id_company as id...
```

Is there a way to do something like this :

```
SELECT COUNT(SELECT * FROM T WHERE id = id_company) as nbapp, id_company...
```

(Doing an implicit join directly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it this way :

```
SELECT (SELECT(COUNT(*) FROM T where id = id_company) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes there's a way Eko, Here's your answer :

```
SELECT tmp_tab.nbapp, id_company...
...
FROM TAB tab 
...
LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT id, COUNT(*) as nbapp FROM T) as tmp_tab
       ON tmp_tab.id = tab.id_company
```

Hope this will help you :)
Good Luck